# 'self' parameter in Python non-class functions

Tags: python, class, tkinter, key-bindings

I'm currently teaching some basic Python to an eager primary school student, and I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around a strange little anomaly in this code for an etch-a-sketch.

```
# myEtchASketch application

from tkinter import *

#####Set variables
canvas_height = 400
canvas_width=600
canvas_colour="black"

p1_x=canvas_width/2
p1_y=canvas_height
p1_colour="blue"
line_width=6
line_length=9

####New window
window=Tk()
window.title("MyEtchASketch")
canvas=Canvas(bg=canvas_colour, height=canvas_height, width=canvas_width,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

##### Functions:

#player controls
def p1_move_N(self):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y-line_length), width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y = p1_y - line_length

def p1_move_S(self):
    global p1_y
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, p1_x, (p1_y+line_length), width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_y=p1_y+line_length

def p1_move_W(self):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, (p1_x-line_length), p1_y, width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x=p1_x-line_length

def p1_move_E(self):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, (p1_x+line_length), p1_y, width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x=p1_x+line_length

def erase_all(self):
    canvas.delete(ALL)


#bind movement to key presses
window.bind("<Up>", p1_move_N)
window.bind("<Down>",p1_move_S)
window.bind("<Left>", p1_move_W)
window.bind("<Right>", p1_move_E)
window.bind("<u>", erase_all)

window.mainloop()
```

The player controls are what's bugging me. The code doesn't work if I don't have `self` added. I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ThisIsNotMyRealUserFolder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: p1_move_N() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I've done a bit of research and found that `self` is used for class methods. As you can see, none of the functions are class methods. The only thing I can think of is that `bind()` treats all functions passed to it as class methods, meaning they require `self` to function correctly.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Self just represents the name of the variable. You could change all of the selfs to x and it should still work. The code doesn't work without "self" because the method still expects 1 parameter to be passed to it (or atleast when it gets called - it gets passed 1 variable)

Comment: You've called the argument `self`, but it's just a name. The real problem here is that you don't understand what arguments tkinter wants to pass to your callback. [Go read about that.](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Comment: @tehjoker: _"Self just represents the name of the variable."_ - no, it does not. It is a reference to the current object, but only if this is a method in a class (which it is not).

Comment: If you're curious you could `print type(self)` in one of those functions. If people here are correct it'll say it's some kind of TK Event class. In which case you probably want to rename `self` to something like `evt`, as the variable name `self`, while arbitrary to the Python interpreter, is not arbitrary to Python coders, and using it there will lead to the sort of confusion you just experienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callable passed to `bind` takes one argument: event. So, the correct way to define the function is e.g.:

```
def p1_move_W(event):
    global p1_x
    canvas.create_line(p1_x, p1_y, (p1_x-line_length), p1_y, width=line_width, fill=p1_colour)
    p1_x=p1_x-line_length
```

`Tk` is going to pass one positional argument, so you are free to call the argument anything you want (`self` works, yes, and `banana` would work as well).

See also [the documentation for Tk event binding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events).

Comment: I would say that `self` absolutely does not work. Technically it works, but the name is exceptionally misleading, leading to code that is hard to understand and maintain.